# Logistic Regression gives unexpected results

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, python

I am trying to predict binary outcome (Response) with a single feature (V1) using `scikit-learn` implementation of Logistic Regression (default parameters).

```
V1: [2.56, 1.12, 1.38, 1.38, 1.25, 1.28, 0.92, 1.51, 2.23, 1.91, 2. , 1.31, 1.41, 1.51, 1.35, 1.12, 1.68, 1.94, 1.61, 2.56, 2.23, 1.54, 1.41, 2.04, 1.18, 1.38, 1.48, 1.54, 1.22, 1.08, 1.77, 2.17, 1.58, 1.38, 1.35, 1.38, 1.35, 1.87, 1.51, 1.77, 1.28, 1.48, 1.74, 1.81, 1.84, 1.84, 1.84, 1.71, 1.84, 1.91, 1.31, 2. , 2.04, 1.35, 1.71, 1.51, 1.31, 1.54, 1.51, 1.38, 1.77, 1.38, 1.12, 1.61, 1.41, 1.68, 1.84, 1.81, 2. , 2.27, 1.05, 2.07, 2. , 1.12, 1.91, 1.97, 1.81, 2.17, 1.28, 1.38, 1.81, 1.48, 1.48, 1.64, 1.97, 2.23, 1.35, 2.2 , 1.77, 1.38, 1.81, 1.58, 1.87, 1.61, 1.58, 1.84, 1.31, 0.92, 1.84, 1.61, 1.18, 1.61, 1.71, 1.31, 1.41, 2.1 , 1.41, 1.81, 1.48, 1.74, 1.41, 1.84, 1.35, 1.54, 1.71, 1.68, 2.1 , 1.61, 1.08, 1.77, 1.61, 1.84, 2.23, 1.91, 1.77, 1.71, 1.68, 2.46, 2. , 2. , 1.97, 2.5 , 2.3 , 2.04, 2.04, 1.94, 1.54, 2.66, 2.04, 1.51, 2.04, 1.91, 2.14, 1.58, 1.77, 1.94, 0.13, 0.16]
```

```
Response:[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]
```

I used k-fold cross-validation with 30 repetitions. The mean test AUC I got is 50%, which means the model has no skill to distinguish the two classes. However, when I plot ROC at different thresholds of feature V1, i get AUC of 0.35, showing a negative correlation with the outcome variable. See figure below

[image: ROC_AUC plot for Response at different thresholds of V1]

Also results from univariate statistical tests give significant p-value (0.02). I used glm function from R for univariate test as I like it better for statiscal anlaysis

```
dm_data <- import("Myexcel.xlsx")

glm.fit <- glm(Response ~ ., data = dm_data, family = binomial("logit"), maxit=100)

[Output]

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.4229     0.9341   0.453   0.6508  
V1           -1.3228     0.5868  -2.254   0.0242 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 127.86  on 147  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 122.54  on 146  degrees of freedom
AIC: 126.54

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Thus I assume that this variable is atleast a moderate predictor of the outcome. but median AUC i get from Logisticregression doesnot support my analysis. My implementation is as follow

```
dataset=pd.read_excel('Myexcel.xlsx')
np_dataset=dataset.values
X= np_dataset[:,1]
y=np_dataset[:,0]
X=X.reshape(-1,1) # reshaped as there is only feature

#Gridsearch for best params

grid_param = {
        'penalty':['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet' 'none'],
        'solver' : ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
        'C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1.0]}
gsc = GridSearchCV(estimator=LogisticRegression(),
                     param_grid=grid_param,
                     scoring='roc_auc',
                     cv=3,
                     n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = gsc.fit(X, y)
best_params = grid_result.best_params_

kfold  = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, n_repeats=30,random_state=1)
ROC_test=[]

for train, test in kfold.split(X,y):
    model = LogisticRegression(C=best_params['C'], penalty=best_params['penalty'], solver=best_params['solver'])
    model.fit(X[train], y[train])
    yhat_test= model.predict_proba(X[test])
    auc_test= roc_auc_score(y[test], yhat_test)
    ROC_test.append(auc_test)
print('Test AUC Median: %.2f' %np.median(ROC_test)*100))

[Output]
Test AUC Median: 50.00%
```

Can anyone please help me to understand the reason for this 0.5 auc of logisticregression model. Thanks

Comment: Hello -- two things.  1. Please show output from one of your logistic regressions and one of your univariate tests. 2. "[W]hen I plot ROC at different thresholds of feature V1" - you should get multiple sets of AUC results, yet you say simply "i get AUC of 0.35."  Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for incomplete information, I have edited my question by adding results of univariate analysis that also uses logistic regression and computes p-value which came out to be 0.02 (less than alpha 0.05) for feature V1. about AUC may be i did not write it clearly but the way you get ROC plot for single feature is always a single plot where you first arrange values of feature and compute true postive and false positive rate for each value of feature (which is refered as threshold). So i think it should be as single plot not multiple.

Comment: The 2nd part of my comment must have been a mistake.  And I don't know how all your code works. But is it possible the negative sign of your coefficient, or the values of your Y, are somehow prompting a reversal, and that your AUC of (.50-.15) should be re-expressed as (.50+.15)?

Comment: the coefficient for V1 is definetly negative becuase if i look closer to data i see that smaller the value of V1 greater is occurrence of event 1. Thus there is a weak correlation that previously was not captured in my CV folds because of highly imbalanced data. Now I balanced the data by enabling 'class_weight' parameter in logisticregression and results are pretty acceptable. I will aslo try to use SMOTE method from 'imblearn' libarary to balance the data and see if it does any good to final AUC.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the plot of response vs V1, and I don't see a *good* predictor here:

[image]

More importantly, if you inspect your data better, you'll see that most of the class 1 samples have x values belonging class 0 as well, e.g. V1 = 1.28 has 2 class-0 responses, and 1 class-1 response.

Comment: Thank you @gunes. I also agree that V1 is not a very good predictor and classes are overlapping and highly imbalanced, but the negative correlation I see from AUC plot at different threshold values of V1 gives me an idea that there is a value of V1 which is somehow able to roughly seperate two classes e.g. V1 = 1.5, but logisticregression is unable to capture even a slight correlation and AUC stays 0.5 for all repititions. I also edit my code and added gridsearchcv for best parameters but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution. Better AUC can be achieved by adjusting for class imbalance. Previously number of samples from class 1 were too small in each repetition that model was unable to make any Prediction on it. I followed some steps from here [optimizing logisticregression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077190/how-to-increase-the-model-accuracy-of-logistic-regression-in-scikit-python)

adding class_weight='balanced' in model deals with class imbalance and it has improved results to median AUC of 0.58. Small addition in model parameters is as follow

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=best_params['C'], penalty=best_params['penalty'], solver=best_params['solver'],class_weight= 'balanced')
```

After fitting this model results are as follow:

```
[Output] 

Test AUC Median: 58.33%
```

Also I see that for all repetitions results are different and better than 0.5. AUC for few repetitions that is stored in list 'ROC_test' is:

```
ROC_test
[Output]
0.66, 0.511,0.60,0.54,0.59,0.65,0.63,0.49,0.63,0.59,0.58,0.60,0.54,0.75...
```

I am now happy with model performance as I am also not expecting much from overlapped values of two classes as mentioned by @gunes.

Comment: You can also try other models. I did a project last year where I had a binary classification problem with a massive class imbalance (about 95% and 5%). A boosted model in a PCA transformed predictor space ended up doing the best. As you have only one predictor, the PCA won't be applicable here :)